# Method in protocol not implemented correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, tapku

I am using the Tapku library to add the calendar in my view. I am getting semantic issue

*calendarMonthView:marksFromDate:toDate:'in protocol 'TKCalendarMonthViewDataSource' not implemented*

on line

```
  @implementation ViewController
```

in my view controller.m

I tried implementing calendarMonthView:marksFromDate:toDate: under TKCalendarMonthViewDataSource but it successfully compiles then shuts down.

This is my code where I have tried implementing it in TKCalendarMonthView.h

```
@protocol TKCalendarMonthViewDataSource <NSObject>

- calendarMonthView:marksFromDate:toDate;


/** A data source that will correspond to marks for the calendar month grid for a particular     month.
 @param monthView The calendar month grid.
 @param startDate The first date shown by the calendar month grid.
 @param lastDate The last date shown by the calendar month grid.
 @return Returns an array of NSNumber objects corresponding the number of days specified in the     start and last day parameters. Each NSNumber variable will give a BOOL value that will be used to     display a dot under the day.
 */


- (NSArray*) calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView*)monthView marksFromDate:(NSDate*)startDate toDate:(NSDate*)lastDate;


@end
```

**Any idea how I can fix it or is my implementation of calendarMonthView:marksFromDate:toDate wrong?**

Thanks!

Comment: You have to actually implement the data source method in your view controller - the class that acts as the data source.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your view controller conforms to the datasource protocol:

viewcontroller.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<TKCalendarMonthViewDataSource>
```

..and implement the `calendarMonthView:marksFromDate:toDate` method in your viewcontroller.m